# Is this possible to set a default value of a function without loosing the polymorphic type of an argument in ocaml

Tags: function, types, polymorphism, ocaml

I have this function to add logs in a file :

```ml
let log_datas f file (datas: 'a list) = 
  let oc = open_out file.file_name in 
    List.iter (fun x -> Printf.fprintf oc "%s" @@ f x) datas;
    close_out oc

let () = let f = string_of_int in  log_datas f {file_name="log"} [1;2]
```

Which works.

I tried to make it by default accepting string list as argument :

```ml
let log_datas ?(f:'a -> string = fun x -> x^"\n") file (datas: 'a list) = 
  let oc = open_out file.file_name in 
    List.iter (fun x -> Printf.fprintf oc "%s" @@ f x) datas;
    close_out oc
```

but when I try

```ml
let () = let f = string_of_int in  log_datas ~f {file_name="log"} [1;2]
```

I get a type error

```ml
23 | let () = let f = string_of_int in  log_datas ~f {file_name="log"} [1;2]
                                                   ^
Error: This expression has type int -> string
       but an expression was expected of type string -> string
       Type int is not compatible with type string
```

An obvious solution would be to make 2 function, one with no `f` argument and one with a `f` argument. But I was wondering, is there any other workaround possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, you have to specify both parameters to keep it polymorphic. Basically, your example could be distilled to,

```
let log ?(to_string=string_of_int) data =
  print_endline (to_string data)
```

If OCaml would keep it polymorphic then the following would be allowed,

```
log "hello"
```

and `string_of_int "hello"` is not well-typed.

So you have to keep both parameters required, e.g.,

```
let log to_string data = 
  print_endline (to_string data)
```

I would also suggest looking into the `Format` module and defining your own polymorphic function that uses format specification to define how data of different types are written, e.g.,

```
let log fmt = 
  Format.kasprintf print_endline fmt
```

Substitute `print_endline` with our own logging facility. The `log` function could be used as `printf`, e.g.,

```
log "%s %d" "hello" 42
```